# Ant Design: Show Popconfirm Before Clear Select

Tags: reactjs, antd

How can I add `Popconfirm` before clearing the `Select` selected value in `antd`? What I've tried:

```
const clearButton = (
  <Popconfirm
    title="Are you sure want to clear the selection?"
    okText="Yes"
    cancelText="No"
  >
    <Button icon={<CloseCircleOutlined />} />
  </Popconfirm>
);

return (
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    allowClear
    clearIcon={clearButton}
  >
    <Option value={1} key={1}>Option 1</Option>
    <Option value={2} key={2}>Option 2</Option>
    <Option value={3} key={3}>Option 3</Option>
  </Select>
);
```

The `Popconfirm` did not even open when I click the button.

Comment: Don’t interrupt your users with a confirm step for this kind of action — instead, offer them an _undo_ option (if your testing shows that they are likely to make mistakes) as a better UX alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `suffixIcon` instead with a little `useState` trick. Here's an example:

```
const [ selectValue, setSelectValue ] = useState( 'lucy' )

function handleClear = () => {
  setSelectValue(() => '')
}
  
const clearButton = <Popconfirm
    title="Are you sure want to clear the selection?"
    onConfirm={handleClear}
>
  <Button 
    icon={<CloseCircleOutlined />} 
  />
</Popconfirm>

.....

<Select
  value={ selectValue }
  suffixIcon={ clearButton }
  onChange={ value => setSelectValue(() => value) }
  options={[
    { value: "jack", label: "Jack" },
    { value: "lucy", label: "Lucy" },
    { value: "Yiminghe", label: "yiminghe" }
  ]}
/>
```

You'll just need to add some css styles to center button icon and maybe change button size.

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-8-5-forked-y3f42s?file=/demo.tsx) a working codesandbox example